# Is there a hook to update / replace values in the "Enable threaded (nested) comments x levels deep" drop down?

Tags: comments

I know how to add a value here that is higher than the max of 10 that is allowed as default (change the value manually in the wp_options table for the value 'thread_comments_depth').

However if I change it in the DB directly the interface will override that value if I go into Settings/Discussions and alter anything else in that page.

I really need the drop down itself to have more numeric values in it and for the correct value to be auto selected when the settings page loads.

[image: A reference image of the Discussion settings page within the WP admin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it's named [`thread_comments_depth_max`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/thread_comments_depth_max/):

```php
add_filter( 'thread_comments_depth_max', function ( $maxdeep ) {
    return 15;
} );
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!